# How to create cookie or session through jquery ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session, cookies

I'm trying to build own javascript API for a chat online. This API is intended to get css file and javascript file and after loading the website it must create a conversation window. I want to share this API for other users.

e.g. If my domain is mydomain.com and includes in html code my javascript API, which downloads css file and javascript file from example.com, what is the best practice to create cookie or session on the user side?

Below is my API:

```
<div id="fb-dialog"></div>
<script async defer src="http://coders.localhost/api/fb-dialog.js">

var apiConf = {

  key: 'YOUR_API_KEY',
  language: {

    /* Your language codes and default greeting */

    "pl" : "Dzień dobry, jestem online. W czym mogę pomóc?",
    "en" : "Hello, I'm online. How can I help you?"

    }

  }

</script>
```

I want share this chat but any conversation must be save on my server.
I want to use a database which will to have a website's ID on the which is installed the API. Before starting a conversation in cookie I want get website ID on the which can I will return response. How can I to do?

My javascript:

```
<script>

$.ajax({
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://coders.localhost/modules/fb-dialog/heading.php"
}).done(function (data) {
   alert("OK");
});

</script>
```

My PHP script:

```
<?php

if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
    // This is not cross-domain request
    exit;
}

$wildcard = false; // Set $wildcard to TRUE if you do not plan to check or limit the domains
$credentials = true; // Set $credentials to TRUE if expects credential requests (Cookies, Authentication, SSL certificates)
$allowedOrigins = array('http://firma.localhost', 'http://jsfiddle.net');

if (!in_array($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'], $allowedOrigins) && !$wildcard) {
    // Origin is not allowed
    exit;
}

$origin = $wildcard && !$credentials ? '*' : $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'];

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: " . $origin);

if ($credentials) {
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
}

header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin");
header('P3P: CP="CAO PSA OUR"'); // Makes IE to support cookies

// Handling the Preflight
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') { 
    exit;
}

if(!isset($_COOKIE['fb-dialog'])) {
    setcookie("fb-dialog", "true", time()+3600, "/");
}else{

  if(!isset($_POST['data'])) {

    if($_COOKIE['fb-dialog'] == 'true') {
    setcookie('fb-dialog', 'false', 0, '/');
    } else {
   setcookie("fb-dialog", "true", time()+3600, "/");
    }
  }
}

// Response
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
echo json_encode(array('status' => 'OK'));

?>
```

The above code is working. I'm getting a status 200 but a cookie is not for proper domain because the script create a cookie for domain coders.localhost

I have two domains:

http://firma.localhost - this is my website

http://coders.localhost - this is remote domain from who I get API

I want create cookie by coders.localhost domain for firma.localhost.

Comment: you have to use `withCredentials` header in request

Comment: I used this and nothing

Answer (score 0):

You can also use plain javascript:

```
document.cookie = "username=admin";
```

or

```
var x = document.cookie;
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have figured already the answer, It would be great if you shared how you resolved it. 
I think the issue maybe due to your `/` configuration in the `setcookie`

Your config:
`setcookie("fb-dialog", "true", time()+3600, "/");`

Try this:
`setcookie("fb-dialog", "true", time()+3600, "http://coders.localhost");`